# To show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\sin nx$ is a Fourier series of $f\in L^{\infty}$ if $na_{n}=O(1).$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I want to show that if $a_{n}\downarrow 0$ and $na_{n}=O(1)$ then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\sin nx$ is a Fourier series of $f\in L^{\infty}$. 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: First, you can show with a Abel transform that the series is converging for all $x$.